# Service Requests from Azure with Known IP (or Range)

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-data-factory

I'm working on an Azure based project whereby we need to talk to a REST based API that is internal to the customers network with the ultimate goal being to consume the responses (JSON if you're interested) within Azure Data Factory

We have discussed multiple ways of talking to this service, such as vNET with Site-to-Site and running a job to save the responses to blob storage, also looking at custom activities that run inside a batch service (but we can't connect this to the vNET) and some other stuff that didn't really go anywhere...

The KEY stumbling block that we have is that we need a way of guaranteeing an IP from the Azure side so that the client can whitelist requests coming in to their network..

Does anyone have any bright ideas on how we can achieve this.. the ideal is that we can code a custom activity within ADF that runs inside a batch service that makes calls to a public IP, but those calls only ever come FROM a known IP or at least a v. small range of IPs..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use Reserved IP Address, and host your API application on a VM or cloud service.

Comment: we do not host/control the API, we need calls going TO it to always have a known IP... or at least a range.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. But similarly, you can use a VM with Reserved IP Address as a bridge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Batch doesn't support joining virtual networks so your ADF DotNet activity cannot have a fixed ip range.
However, Azure Batch supports certificate management for VM nodes(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/batch-api-basics/#cert) so if the web endpoint you are calling can be protected by a client certificate while opening traffic to all public ip addresses, then you can choose to use the certificate based authentication in ADF DotNet activity.

On the other hand, ADF DotNet activity can also be run on HDInsight clusters and I believe HDInsight supports virtual network (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-extend-hadoop-virtual-network/). You need to first create and configure your own HDInsight cluster with virtual network enabled). Then you create an HDInsight BYOC linked service with ADF to run your DotNet activity.

Comment: will azure batch ever support vNets? Is it in the pipeline?